# Multiple queries on same table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a table like this:

```
users_info:
userID | title     | content
1      | Firstname | Tester
1      | Lastname  | Wester
2      | Firstname | LKks
```

I want to check if the firstname and lastname already exist in the database with a PHP function.
How can I run a simple query to check if there are any results?
the variable for firstname is: $firstname and $lastname for the lastname.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow , could you share what you have tried till now , and where your are stucked ?

Comment: I can fix the result I want with to queries.
SELECT title, content FROM users_info WHERE title=Firstname AND content=$firstname
and a second for lastname.

Comment: I think the best way to go is sub-queries.
SELECT `userID` from `users_info` where `title` = 'Firstname' and `content` = '$firstname' AND `userID` IN (SELECT `userID` from `users_info` where `title` = 'Lastname' and `content` = '$lastname')

If you get any results. you have rows with this firstname and lastname with the same id.

Comment: share what you have done till , now so someone will improve that query

Comment: Thanks Guy Schlider!!
His query worked perfect for me!

Comment: Great, I'm posting it as an answer, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go is sub-queries.

```
SELECT userID from users_info where title = 'Firstname' and content = '$firstname' AND
userID IN (SELECT userID from users_info where title = 'Lastname' and content = '$lastname')
```

If you get any results. you have rows with this firstname and lastname with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tableValidate($firstname, $lastname)
{
$query = $dbConnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE title = ? AND content = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, 'Firstname');
$query->bindValue(2, $firstname);
$query->execute();
try
{
    $result = $query->rowCount();
} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$queryOne = $dbConnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE title = ? AND content = ?");
$queryOne->bindValue(1, 'Lastname');
$queryOne->bindValue(2, $lastname);
$queryOne->execute();
try
{
    $resultOne = $queryOne->rowCount();
} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}

if($result > 0 && $resultOne > 0)
{
    echo "Firstname and Lastname Exists";
}
else if ($result > 0)
{
    echo "Firstname Exists";
}
else if ($resultOne > 0)
{
    echo "Lastname Exists";
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}
}
```